# Issue with a 404 error using socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I've recently gotten into socket.io, during a long-term project of mine. Which is probably why I am having such a hard time of it, because their "getting started" sections don't take into account you may already be deep into development of your own application. The main issue is it connecting, it won't do it, client-side that is.

I keep getting a `404 not found` which is cause by `CANNOT POST /socket.io/` Which it is right, it can't obviously, mainly because that is not where the socket.io location is (it is in node_modules per usual). Secondly if I create a route for this, it does absolutely nothing. So here is code initializing it:

```
/*jshint esversion: 6*/
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const expressValidator = require('express-validator');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require('passport');
const db = require('./config/db');

// Init App
const app = express();

// Init http server
const server = http.createServer(app);

// init socket
const io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

Here is the clientside trying to connect to it:

```
if (window.location.hostname == 'playkog.net' || window.location.hostname == 'www.playkog.net') {
  var port = 443;
} else {
  var port = 8080;
}

var connected = false;
var socket = io.connect(window.location.hostname + ':' + port, { 'connect timeout': 5000 });

// Connection Successful
socket.on('connect', function () {
  console.log('a user connected');
  connected = true;
});

socket.on('disconnect', function () {
  console.log('user disconnected');
  connected = false;
});
```

I imagine I'll have to connect to a different port, however I'm not sure which, nor if that is my issue (or only issue). Of course be extremely new to this kind of stuff (amateur at best) some of these things just go right over my head.

Here is a screenshot of my console

[image: Screenshot of the console]

Comment: Are you doing server.listen(), and if yes, on what port?

Comment: "Which it is right, it can't obviously, mainly because that is not where the socket.io location is (it is in node_modules per usual)" - this is wrong. When you connect socket.io into express, express automatically makes that URL available to the socket.io js file. It's the intended behaviour.

Comment: Is playkog.net running on the above express code?

Comment: From what I can tell, your Node.js code is running on HTTP and then NGINX is bouncing to that from HTTPS, correct? I see no mention of SSL certificates or anything in your above code...!

Comment: Yes NGINX is used. I had already set it up with SSL so I didn;t really want to undo all that. The server is listening on port 8080.

Comment: I have fixed it. I was using app.listen instead of server.listen... I'm a dumby. Also, why doesn't `app.get('port')` work?